# The type 'CoreWCF.ServiceHostBase' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UnityWcfLifetimeManager<T>'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-7.0

I've upgraded from .NET 4.8 framework to .NET 7 and I can't seem to get rid of the following error;

`The type 'CoreWCF.ServiceHostBase' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UnityWcfLifetimeManager<T>'`

```
using CoreWCF;
using Unity.Lifetime;

namespace Chiro.Cdf.UnityWcfExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unity lifetime manager to support <see cref="ServiceHostBase"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityServiceHostBaseLifetimeManager : UnityWcfLifetimeManager<ServiceHostBase>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the appropriate extension for the current lifetime manager.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The registered extension for the current lifetime manager, otherwise, null if the extension is not registered.</returns>
        protected override UnityWcfExtension<ServiceHostBase> FindExtension()
        {
            return UnityServiceHostBaseExtension.Current;
        }

        protected override LifetimeManager OnCreateLifetimeManager()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of solutions I saw on the internet, but nothing really seems to work

Comment: What is `UnityWcfLifetimeManager`?

Comment: Hmmm... WCF and Life time management aren't really supported in .NET 6.0 any more. I'm not sure what this class is used for, but try to just delete it.